# How to create random length String containing multiple single letter?

Tags: java, random

The task of mine is to create a random length A letter generator. It has to create 50 lines of Strings containing a random number of A letter. To be honest, I think I am really close to conclusion, but still, I know I am missing something. Currently, the generator of mine is creating random numbers.

The task is concentrated about doing it with for loop.

Furthermore - if there is an easier way to write the code of mine than that what I have done - I will be grateful for tips.

I tried the different way of expressing the for loop, none of them got me close to my task.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class RandomGenerator{
    private static final String alpha = "a";
    private static final String data = alpha;

    private static final String combinationOFA = alpha;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    for (int n=0; n<50; n++){
        Random theGeneratorForLength = new Random();
    }

    System.out.println("String : " + combinationOFA);
}

public static String generateRandomALetter(int length) {
Random theGeneratorAlpha = new Random();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    int aLengthVariable = 
    theGeneratorAlpha.nextInt(combinationOFA.length());
    char alphaTeta = combinationOFA.charAt(aLengthVariable);

    sb.append(alphaTeta);
    }

return sb.toString();

}

}
```

I would like this code to create 50 Strings made of random length multiplied A letter

Comment: but you are not even calling `generateRandomALetter`

Comment: So, create a loop and iterate 50 times. And inside this loop, generate a random string. To generate a random string, first generate a random length N, then append the letter 'a' N times to a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something like this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class RandomGenerator {
    private static final String alpha = "a";
    private static final String data = alpha;

    // I removed final from here. reusing your string variable for storing values.
    private static String combinationOFA = alpha;

    // Introduced two variable max and min to find out max and min
    // characters you need to generate
    private static final Integer max = 50;
    private static final Integer min = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++) {
            Random theGeneratorForLength = new Random();

            // you need to call method you created below with proper values.
            // min and max are max and min random values for you
            // and assigned value to combinationOFA
            combinationOFA = generateRandomALetter(theGeneratorForLength.nextInt(max - min) + min);

            // moved this line inside the loop to print
            System.out.println("String " + (n + 1) + " :" + combinationOFA);
        }
    }

    public static String generateRandomALetter(int length) {
        Random theGeneratorAlpha = new Random();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            int aLengthVariable =
                    theGeneratorAlpha.nextInt(combinationOFA.length());
            char alphaTeta = combinationOFA.charAt(aLengthVariable);

            sb.append(alphaTeta);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It actually made everything. Now i have to understand this code of yours. I feel so dumb...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
import java.util.*;

class RandomGenerator {
    private static final char A = 'A';

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Random theGeneratorForLength = new Random();
        for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++) {
            int length = theGeneratorForLength.nextInt(50);
            char[] chars = new char[length];
            Arrays.fill(chars, A);
            String line = new String(chars);
            lines.add(line);
        }
        System.out.println("String : " + lines);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) from Apache Commons Lang lib

```
public class RandomStringGenerator {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        char[] charSet= {'a','b','c','d'};
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
            int length = (int)(Math.random()*100);
            System.out.println(RandomStringUtils.random(length,charSet));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maximumSymbolsInString = 50;
    int countOfStrings = 10;

    List<String> strings = new Random().ints(0, maximumSymbolsInString)
            .limit(countOfStrings)
            .mapToObj(el-> new String(new char[maximumSymbolsInString])
                                            .replace('\0', 'A')
                                            .substring(el))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (String string : strings) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

In Java 11 you could use new method of class String: repeate(int) for each string generation. Like `"A".repeate(50)`

Answer (score 0):

I've written a basic program with just the loops. Was this the output you were looking for?

```
import java.util.Random;

class RandomString {
   private static final String alpha = "a";

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       int length = 0;
       for (int n = 0; n < 50; n++) {
           Random l = new Random();
           length = l.nextInt(50) + 1;

           for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
               StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               sb = sb.append(alpha);
               System.out.print("String: "+sb.toString());

           }
           System.out.println();
       }
   }
}
```